# Native HTML tag for small caps

Tags: html, css, fonts, smallcaps

In CSS, I can do small caps like:

```
<span style="font-variant: small-caps;">Jane Doe</span>
```

But is there a native HTML tag for small caps?

Comment: HTML (since after HTML4) deals with semantics only, not with presentation. What semantics would such an element bring?

Comment: This https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong is worth a read. It disentangles the semantics and the styling of em and strong tags. I can’t think of a convention which would normally use small caps to convey a meaning, but maybe you know of one?

Comment: @Kaiido so why "<b>" is bold and "<i>" is italics for example?

Comment: @robertspierre - They aren't. "<b>" is ["a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) and "<i>" is ["a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element)

Comment: @Kaiido can you convert this into an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : there is clearly not native HTML element for small-cap styling. There is no accurate answer to the OP's question. Besides, the OP is aware of the CSS approaches.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a native HTML tag specifically for small caps text. To display text in small caps, you can use CSS to style your text. You can apply the font-variant property to achieve this effect. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .small-caps {
    font-variant: small-caps;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is normal text.</p>
<p class="small-caps">This is small caps text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In the example above, the

element with the class "small-caps" has the font-variant property set to "small-caps," which renders the text in small capital letters. You can apply this style to any HTML element by giving it the appropriate class or by targeting elements with CSS selectors.